# My vim theme (gruvbox) is not being applied

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vimrc

im trying to set this **theme for vim**: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/gruvbox .

I have installed it:

1. I added the Plug to `.vimrc`

`Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'`

2. From a opened vim editor I executed the command: `:PlugInstall`

[image]

And is everything installed.

After that I set colors in `~/.vim/colors`:
[image]

And  plugin theme data seems to be in :

```
~/.vim/plugged
```

[image]

So I open a test  file and I get this:

[image]

Instead of something like:

[image]

I dont really know what im doing wrong.

My  current `.vimrc`  is :

```
"CONFIGURACIONES BASICAS"

"syntax on
"set number
"set background=dark
"set cursorcolumn
"set ignorecase
"set showmatch
"set hlsearch
"set history=1000

"CONFIFURACIONES DE PLUGINS"


call plug#begin()

Plug 'preservim/NERDTree'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips', {'for': ['sh', 'python', 'markdown']}
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets', {'for': ['sh', 'python', 'markdown']}
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'

Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'

call plug#end()


let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType    = '<C-n>'
let g:SuperTabCrMapping                = 0
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger           = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger      = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger     = '<s-tab>'
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion   = ['<C-j>', '<C-n>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-k>', '<C-p>', '<Up>']

let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
let g:UltiSnipsListSnippets="<c-t>"
```

**PD:** I have commented `CONFIGURACIONES BASICAS` section of my `.vimrc` because I thought it cloud have been some conflicts between plugins, but not seems that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a colorcheme line. Add this to your vimrc file, make sure you do not add it before the anywhere before the plug#end line.

colorscheme gruvbox